# If !0 is truthy then how come "true && !0" returns true and not !0?

Tags: javascript

From what I understand if both values are truthy it should return the last truthy value which in this case should be !0.

Comment: `!0` evaluates as `true` in JavaScript.

Comment: `!0` is converting 0 to a bool (`false`) and negating it. You're simply doing `true && true`

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question with actual code examples.

Comment: Poor coding practices lead to silly questions. If you know you need a Boolean value prior to the test, then take control and cast the value. Avoid sillyness

Comment: "true && !0" doesn't _return_ anything. It is a string. What is the expression you are referring to in your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a not javascript developer, but this is quite simple.

> int 0 **equals** int 0
>
> int 1 **equals** int 1
>
> int 0 == bool false **equals** true *(it means JS threats 0 as false and casts 0 to bool)*
>
> int 1 == bool true **equals** true *(it means JS threats 1 as true and casts 1 to bool)*
>
> bool !0 **equals** true (!0 becomes true, because the opposite of true is false, and 0 is threated here as 0 because ! interprets and casts it as a boolean)
>
> !1 **equals** false

As far as my javascript knowledge goes, once you use `!` it will become a boolean as it tries to cast int to bool.

`true && !0 == true` because `!0` is true.

Basically it's parsing as
`true && true == true` thus returning boolean true, and not !0.

Answer (score 1):

While the answer of Droppy is correct, it lacks a proper in-depth explanation of the encountered behavior:

`!{statement}` is in human readable form simply `not {statement}`.

`!` is the logical NOT operator, it reverses the [truthiness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) or [falsiness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) of `{statement}`.

`0` in this case is not converted to anything - it is just a falsy value and since `!` is an operator, it returns the result of the inverted falsy/truthy match. From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators):

> Returns false if its single operand can be converted to true; otherwise, returns true.

You can easily get the boolean result of a statements falsiness/truthiness by doing: `!!{statement}`. For your example, `!!0` gives `false`, likewise `!!1` gives `true`.

If we were to write our own logical IS and NOT function according to JS standards, it would look like:

```js
function logicalIs(statement) {
  if(statement === undefined) return false;
  if(statement === null) return false;
  if(statement === false) return false;
  if(statement === "") return false;
  if(statement === '') return false;
  if(statement === 0) return false;
  if(typeof(statement) === 'number' && isNaN(statement)) return false;
  // document.all: Willful violation for IE legacy reasons
  if(statement === document.all) return false; 
  return true;
}

function logicalIsNot(statement) {
  if(statement === undefined) return true;
  if(statement === null) return true;
  if(statement === false) return true;
  if(statement === "") return true;
  if(statement === '') return true;
  if(statement === 0) return true;
  if(typeof(statement) === 'number' && isNaN(statement)) return true;
  // document.all: Willful violation for IE legacy reasons
  if(statement === document.all) return true;
  return false;
}

let truthy = [true, 1, 'a', "b", [], {}, function(){}];
let falsy = [false, 0, '', "", NaN, null, undefined, document.all];

console.log('logical truthy: ', JSON.stringify(truthy.map(logicalIs)));
console.log('logical falsy: ', JSON.stringify(falsy.map(logicalIs)));

console.log('logical not truthy:', JSON.stringify(truthy.map(logicalIsNot)));
console.log('logical not falsy:', JSON.stringify(falsy.map(logicalIsNot)));
```